# "template.buildRenderNodes is not a function" on latest Ember release

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

**HTML and JS** (non-minified versions)

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- <ember> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/ember.js/ember.min.js"></script>
        <!-- </ember> -->

        <!-- <app> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/templates.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
        <!-- </app> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

*app.min.js*

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
```

*templates.min.js* (the templates are compiled using [gulp-ember-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ember-templates))

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["index"] = Ember.Handlebars.template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  return "";
},"useData":true});
```

**Description**

When opening the page in a browser, the following error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: template.buildRenderNodes is not a function
```

I'm using the latest version of both Ember and jQuery. When searching for this error I found people having this issue whilst upgrading to Ember 1.13, but I'm using Ember 2.0.0 and didn't call any deprecated method on purpose, actually I'm only using my generated templates (which are empty, because I didn't put any content in yet; see above) and `Ember.Application.create()`.

I also found out that Ember works when including `ember-template-compiler.js` and keeping the templates uncompiled inside the HTML (using the Handlebars-script-tags).

**Question**

Is it a bug in Ember or am I missing something? It seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a version of Ember that is using the new Handlebars compatible templating engine [HTMLBars](http://colintoh.com/blog/htmlbars). To make sure your templates compile using this new syntax you will need to add the `isHTMLBars: true` option into the Gulp task for `gulp-ember-templates`, more formation can be found [in the README](https://github.com/swelham/gulp-ember-templates#optionsishtmlbars).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is right, but it wasn't the `isHTMLBars` but rather the `compiler` option that failed. It's also strange that the npm module of `ember-template-compiler` doesn't work the same as the bower one.